# How do I save iptables config?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, port

I have just installed Webmin on a Ubuntu server. According to [the docs](http://webmin.com/firewall.html) you need to open up port 10000 (which is what Webmin runs on), with this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
```

It then says you need to apply the firewall configuration with:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

However, this command doesn't work for me. Is there a different command that saves the changes on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your iptables rule is active once you execute it. Issuing a restart merely restores your iptables config to however it was last saved. There is no need to do the restart.

Comment: and it will go away on the next reboot

Answer (score 6):

there is a package that contains a system service to restore

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

put rules in /etc/iptables/rules.

one way to do this is:

```
sudo bash -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules"
```

Answer (score 3):

On many Linux distributions, you can save changes made to iptables config by:

```
service iptables save
```

or alternately

```
/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

But this doesn't **activate** changes, it merely makes them permanent.  The moment you executed the `iptables` command, the change was active.  This command makes changes in real time.

Comment: there is no such service in the current version of Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 2):

```
iptables-save
iptables-restore
```

will save rules in a plain text file, and usually restored on system sturup by the init.d script.  see iptables.conf e iptables man for details

Comment: these commands dont exist.

Comment: Simply forgotten a dash. Fixed