# Webmin and/or port 10000 not working

Tags: ubuntu, port

I've recently installed [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com) on a Ubuntu server but I can't get it to work. I asked a [recent question](https://serverfault.com/questions/65181/how-do-i-save-iptables-config) about saving iptables but it turns out you don't need to "save" iptables changes.

Anyway, I still can't get Webmin working after opening the port up:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
```

It seems that either the command is not opening up port 10000, or there is a separate problem with Webmin. If I run `iptables -L` I see lines like the following, but no port 10000:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:5555 state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:8002 state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:9001 state NEW
```

However, there is a line:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:webmin
```

Any ideas why Webmin is not working? The IP address works fine and we can view web sites on the server, but `https://[ip]:10000/` (or http) doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to access it from inside your network?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I managed to fix this following the advice [on this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) by adding the rule to the beginning of the list, rather than the end. If you append it, the rule comes after all the traffic has been dropped, which doesn't work.

This command did it:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I have to do this after every reboot.. what is going on?

Comment: @Ortix92 You need to save the rules and get them to reload on boot. The firewall section of [this page](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server/) should help.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the `port` and `listen` in \etc\webmin\miniserv.conf

example:

```
port=1000
listen=1000
```

Then restart webmin:

```
/etc/init.d/webmin restart
```

Now use:

```
https://iporhost:1000/
```

Comment: don't you mean to use 10000 and not 1000?

Comment: use another port (ex: 1000) instead of 10000

Comment: This solution really helped me in my case. My ISP was blocking the port 10000

Answer (score 0):

Does it work locally on the server where webmin is installed (ie. http[s]://127.0.0.1:10000)? If you don't want to install a graphical webbrowser to test this, just try it with wget or something.

The dpt:webmin  part of your output just means there is an entry for webmin on port 10000 in your /etc/services and iptables looks it up to give a more meaningful output (service type instead of hostname).

Comment: Yes, trying `https://localhost:10000` with wget grabs the regular login page. So internally it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure webmin is configured to listen from remote addresses. This is under webmin configuration>IP access control.

Comment: ...but I can't access Webmin. I suppose I may be able to use Lynx locally to check, but Lynx is always funny with anything more than basic HTML (i.e. certificates, cookies, etc). I'm sure by default you can access from remote addresses - that's what it's for!

Answer (score 0):

maybe blocked/forwarded on the router? it's not a usual port to be open on every router... i happen to have it open on one only because it's DMZ'd. Also you don't mention how you're trying to connect. my corporate firewall blocks anything other than port 80 and 443 so to access from their system I have to change it to a port that they permit.

Answer (score 0):

as another possible solution (since you didn't mention this...) if possible, VPN to your network. VPN should permit connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the above answer to include the `-i` option which allows you to specify which interface the rule should be applied to. When I ran the rule without the option, it was not showing up in `iptables -L` but after specifying the interface, it worked like a charm.

From the iptables -h docs:

```
[!] --in-interface -i input name[+]
                                network interface name ([+] for wildcard)
```

So, to apply the rule to any ethernet interface you would do the following:

`iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 10000` **-i eth+** `-j ACCEPT`

Or, to listen on on a specific ethernet interface (eth1, for example) you would do:

`iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 10000` **-i eth1** `-j ACCEPT`

Now, `iptables -L` should show it at the top of the output and you will be able to access webmin's web interface. HTH.